# Creation of an upload btn with javascript and Handeling in code behind the uploaded file

Tags: javascript, .net

http://code.google.com/p/upload-at-click/

am trying to create an upload btn in img style, i found this site, my quetion is the in the example the code is :

> var uploader = document.getElementById('Imgbox1');
>                         upclick({ element: uploader,
>                             action: '/path_to/you_server_script.php',**
>                             onstart: function (filename) {
>                                 alert('Start upload: ' + filename);
>                             },
>                             oncomplete:
>                                         function (response_data) {
>                                             alert(response_data);
>                                         }
>                         });

i am working in .net, the example gice the action the path of .php file ,if i want to point do i point to the ascx or what , to be able to upload the file ? or to a code that be done on the server side but how is that

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.NET` on the server-side, in the same way that `PHP` is, this is completely irrelevant as your question is related to Javascript.

If you're asking how to handle the uploaded files, you would generally look into `Request.Files`